# Qual o significado de Nodo?

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Estou estudando pilhas e filas, abaixo foi me dado um código para analisar. O código primeiramente cria fila depois enfileira os valores. Após isso ele remove cada um dos valores da fila e avisa se obteve sucesso removendo ou não o valor.

O que não entendi foi o significado de nodo, se é uma struct que armazena ponteiro ou algo assim.

Código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct nodo 
{
    float dado;
    struct nodo *proximo;
} Nodo;


int push(Nodo **inicio, float dado) {
    Nodo *nodo;
    if ((nodo = (Nodo *) malloc(sizeof(Nodo)))  == NULL) 
      return 0;

    nodo->dado    = dado;
    nodo->proximo = NULL;  

    if (*inicio != NULL) 
        nodo->proximo = *inicio;

    *inicio = nodo;
    return 1;   
}

int pop(Nodo **inicio, float *dado) {
    if (*inicio == NULL) 
        return 0;
    else {
        Nodo *auxiliar = *inicio;
        *dado = (*inicio)->dado;
        *inicio = (*inicio)->proximo;
        free(auxiliar);
    }
    return 1;       
}

void DestroiLista(Nodo **inicio) {
    Nodo *ptrAux;
    while (*inicio != NULL) {   
        ptrAux = *inicio;
        *inicio = ptrAux->proximo;
        printf("Destruindo %.1f\n",ptrAux->dado);       
        free(ptrAux);
    }
}

int main( ) {
    int i;
    float dado;
    Nodo *pilha = NULL; 

    push(&pilha, 5);
    push(&pilha, 2);
    push(&pilha, 7);
    push(&pilha, 6);
    for (i=0;i<6;i++) {
        if (pop(&pilha,&dado)) 
            printf("Deu certo remover o valor %f da fila\n",dado);
        else
            printf("Nao deu certo remover um elemento da pilha\n");
    }
    DestroiLista(&pilha);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso parece uma implementação de uma [lista encadeada (linked list)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). Ele armazena a referência para o próximo item, caso não exista, então `null`.

> é uma coleção linear de elementos de dados, cuja ordem se dá com cada elemento apontando para próximo

[image]

Na imagem, cada **bloco de duas casas** é um **nodo** e a última casa de cada bloco é a **referência para o próximo nodo**. Nesse exemplo, posso representar assim:

```
nodo1.valor   = 12
nodo1.proximo = &nodo2

nodo2.valor   = 99
nodo2.proximo = &nodo3

nodo3.valor   = 37
nodo3.proximo = null
```

> O operador `&` foi colocado apenas para enfatizar que o valor a ser armazenado no atributo `nodo.proximo` é o endereço do nodo desejado